# ApexPages.StandardSetController.getSelected() method is returning System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, visualforce

```java
public class showSelectedRecordsController2 {
    //public static List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
    public static List<Contact> conList {set;get;}
    public static ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
     // Constructor     
    public showSelectedRecordsController2(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
    {
        setCon = controller;
       // conList = (List<Contact>)setCon.getSelected();  
        System.debug('Contact Info size = ' + setCon.getSelected().size());
        
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Contact> getSelectedContacts() {
       conList = (List<Contact>)setCon.getSelected(); 
         System.debug('Contact Info = ' + conList);
        return conList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. When dealing with errors, it's important to provide the full text of the error message, along with the stack trace. Paraphrasing generally only makes it harder to determine what the issue is (and how to resolve it). A title and a code dump are also generally not sufficient. In this case, I think it'll be important to know _how_ you're calling this code when you're getting this error. Are you trying to unit test this? Are you trying to view it as part of an Aura component? You should [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Also, side notes. 1) The code formatting that stackexchange uses doesn't have "apex" as a supported language. The closest we have is java (which happens to provide pretty good syntax highlighting for Apex too). 2) I suspect that the `static` modifier on `setcon` is going to be important here. The constructor isn't going to be called if Aura is calling the static method. This is probably a sign that you're trying to go about this in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two approaches you're taking in your class are incompatible.

`ApexPages.StandardSetController` is only an option if your controller is being used [for a Visualforce page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm) whereas an `AuraEnabled` method is something you would use with Aura and Lightning Web Components. There isn't a circumstance where your constructor will be called (with a `StandardSetController` passed in) and the context for your static `setCon` property to still be visible in the static Aura method `getSelectedContacts`. In fact, your constructor will not be called when calling `getSelectedContacts` in the first place.

Unfortunately, I think you will need to take a step back and consider how users are going to be accessing this functionality.

Comment: In that case how to fetch the selected records through AuraEnabled methods?

Comment: These seems a bit like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need users to do something in Lightning, your solution should be a Lightning component. Take a look at lightning-data-table which would be my guess as to what you would need to use to work with a collection of records.